# I'm able to login via "psql" as "posgres" with any linux user - is this a security issue?

Tags: security, postgresql, user-permissions, psql

I used `sudo su postgres` and set up my database while logged in as the linux user `postgres`. After exiting to my normal shell, logged in as my non-root user, I can simply use `psql -U postgres` and then do whatever I want with any database, Postgres user, etc. Is this normal, and does it pose a security risk?

Comment: What does your `pg_hba.conf` say?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Aha, thanks :) Do you think it's a good practice to modify the `all` in the `local` to read `postgres` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your `pg_hba.conf` is set to `trust` for `local` connections. If you trust your local users, that's not too bad, though I don't think it's ever a great idea for production.

Make *really sure* that `trust` isn't set for `host` (network) connections - it's sort-of OK to allow `trust` for 127.0.0.1 but it's something I'd only actually consider doing for a test setup, never for production. You should be using `md5` password auth or a strong security mechanism like certificate auth, Kerberos, etc for network clients.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, Craig - I'll use md5, since the server is only accessible in a private network. What would you say to my question posed above in the OP comments?

Comment: @orokusaki It depends on whether or not you trust your local users (and the security of the host system to prevent an illicit login) -- Generally as Craig said I would not do this in production.